# WSO2 analytics dashboard javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

When I started WSO2(6.5.0) analytics dashboard i got this exception.
How can I fix this and see dashboard with analytics?

```
[2020-01-31 16:25:40,595]  WARN {io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline} - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception. io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1194)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    ... 16 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue has been identified before[1] and has been fixed in EI 6.6.0 version. Since this only a warning message, this should not interrupt the functionality of the Analytics dashboard.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/4052

Comment: Thank You for the response. is it fixed in the 6.6.0. very first time the analytics dashboard showed up and after that it showed this warn message in console. Can you let me know am i did something wrong please. I will check the 6.6.0 version. thank you